# Error using "save" to save in a directory

Tags: matlab, save, workspace

I would like to save a workspace in another directory and I have written the following in Matlab for it:

```
fileName = [datestr(now, 'dd-mmm-yyyy_HHMMSS') '_test'];
save('C:\Users\User\project',fileName)
```

It gives me the error: `Error using save: '05-Nov-2019_083736_test' is not a valid variable name.`

But if I run without giving an address of the directory it workes perfectly.

Why does it happen?

Comment: You have to merge the path and the filename between square brackets: `save(['C:\Users\User\project' fileName])` in order to create the complete filename. As it is wrtitten now, the first part is interpreted as the actual path and filename, while the second parameter (filename) is interpreted as the variable to be saved which is not defined in the workspace, thus the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [il_raffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4806927/il-raffa)'s suggestion from the comments (with a small correction):

```
save(['C:\Users\User\project\' fileName])
%                           ^ add a folder separator here
```

or use the [`fullfile`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) function, to avoid errors due to forgotten folder separators:

```
save(fullfile('C:\Users\User\project', fileName));
```

This works also for subfolders and filenames, e.g.

```
save(fullfile('C:\Users\User\project', 'matfiles', fileName));
```